# Loop through Outbox with Inbox, Delete message with same subject line from outbox

Tags: vba, outlook

Im trying to look through 2 different boxes(inbox & Outbox), compare the subject and delete the message in the outbox when a match is found. What am I doing incorrectly? Do I need to create another Folder object for each box? **EDIT Im getting a "runtime error 13; type mismatch"**

```
Sub DEID()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst
    Set objIFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
    Set objOFolder = objFolder.Folders("Outbox")

    Dim Item, OItem As Outlook.MailItem

    For Each Item In objIFolder.Items
        Set ISub = Right(CStr(Item.Subject), Len(Item.Subject) - 6)
        Set ISub = CStr(ISub)
        For Each OItem In objOFolder.Items
            Set OSub = Right(CStr(OItem.Subject), Len(OItem.Subject) - 6)
            Set ISub = CStr(OSub)
            If StrComp(ISub = OSub, 1) = 0 Then
                OItem.Delete
            End If
        Next OItem
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst` return the correct store on your system?  It doesn't on mine.  If I type `? Session.Folders.GetFirst.Name` on my system it displays "Outlook Data File" which is the default store but not the one that holds emails if you use the wizard to install your email accounts.

Comment: You appear to be trying to match emails by subject excluding the first six characters,  If I send you an email with a subject of "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" your reply is likely to have a subject like "Re: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". Stripping off the first six characters will not make these match.  You need to be more careful in preparing the subjects for comparison.

Comment: On my system, emails only remain in "Outbox" until they are sent.  After that they are in "Sent Items".

Comment: To me this is dangerous.  You assume subjects are unique.  At the very least I would check the recipient of the sent email matched the sender of the received email.  Are you assuming the reply will contain the text of the original email? This is very common but is not compulsory.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the "Re: " change to the subject. I have the outbox set on a delay. Im sure it works. Im using the same code else where.

Comment: I know subjects are unique

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps out at me is you are using a `set` command on a value type (subject, which is a string), which you don't need and should cause an error.

```
Dim Item, OItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ISub, OSub As String

For Each Item In objIFolder.Items
    ISub = Right(CStr(Item.Subject), Len(Item.Subject) - 6)
    ISub = CStr(ISub)
    For Each OItem In objOFolder.Items
        OSub = Right(CStr(OItem.Subject), Len(OItem.Subject) - 6)
        ISub = CStr(OSub)
        If StrComp(ISub = OSub, 1) = 0 Then
            OItem.Delete
        End If
    Next OItem
Next Item
```

One other observation...  This line:

```
ISub = CStr(OSub)
```

Seems to me like it will force the next condition to always be true.  Unless I misunderstand, that seems like a mistake.

I also think the String conversion are unnecessary since subject is already a string.

This would be my final version:

```
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst
Set objIFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
Set objOFolder = objFolder.Folders("Outbox")

Dim Item, OItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ISub, OSub As String

For Each Item In objIFolder.Items
    ISub = Right(Item.Subject, Len(Item.Subject) - 6)
    For Each OItem In objOFolder.Items
        OSub = Right(OItem.Subject, Len(OItem.Subject) - 6)
        If ISub = OSub Then
            OItem.Delete
        End If
    Next OItem
Next Item
```

Comment: I got "runtine error '-2147221233 (8004010f)' The attempted operaion faild. An object could not be found."

Comment: If you step through the code, where did the error occur?  It was probably a typo...  I didn't attempt to run this (I don't want to delete them, and besides, my outbox is empty)

Comment: `Set objIFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")` is the breaking point

Comment: Is it possible `Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst` is not what you think it is?  Just guessing here...  maybe explicitly call out which folder you want.  For example `Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("youremail@yourdomain.com")`

Comment: It works elsewhere. Now that we set it explicitly, Im getting a "runtime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument" same breaking point

Comment: Add a watch on objNS.Folders, and go through each of the items (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc).  See which one is the mailbox you are interested in.  Then go to the "Name" property, and be sure that's what is in the objNS.Folders(< >).  Does all of that check out?  Hard to diagnse from my end, of course, since presumably we have very different Exchange setups

Comment: I only have one account. Set up.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are dimming `Item` and `OItem` as `Outlook.MailItem` - you can have other items in the Inbox folder (hence the Type Mismatch error), such as `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem`. Dim these variables as a generic `Object`.

Secondly, you are deleting items in a collection while you are looping through it. Do not do that - use a down loop (`for i = Items.Count to 1 step -1`).

Thirdly, do not loop through all items in a folder - this is hugely inefficient, let Outlook do the job  - for the inner use Items.Find / FindNext or `Items.Restrict` with a query like `@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" like '%some value%'`.

For the outer loop, again, dd not loop, retrieve all subjects in a single call using `MAPIFolder.GetTable()` / Table.Columns.Add / `Table.GetArray` / etc. - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.table?view=outlook-pia